# What is the limit value of this function (sin..)

Tags: convergence-divergence

I wanted to ask you a question about this specific function:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left( \sin(\sqrt{x})-\sin(\sqrt{x+1})\right)$$

Somehow I can't comprehend how to do this task
On one hand sin has its specific attributes like jumping around $1$ and $- 1$..
So it's divergent ?
Or does it converge against $0$.. I don't really know
It would be nice if you could give me a hint/solution

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the inequality $$|\sin x-\sin y|\le |x-y|, \forall x,y$$
and then apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Quite a splendid solution!!

Comment: Aren't you missing - x - y <= sin x - y ?

Comment: @Kusottare I think you are implying the inequality $|\sin x|\le x$, but in my opinion it makes no sense here.

Comment: Ok I will answer you with a new comment about my ideas.. could you correct improve them ? I think it makes more sense this way for me

Answer (score 0):

Because x+1> x I can change the algebraic signs in sin
(sin(sqrt(x) - sin(sqrt(x+1)) = -2 lim x -> infinity cos (sqrt(x) + sqrt(x+1)/2) sin (sqrt(x+1 - x )/2)

Now I expand my sin
(sin(sqrt(x) - sin(sqrt(x+1)) = -2 lim x -> infinity cos (sqrt(x) + sqrt(x+1)/2) sin ((sqrt(x+1) - (sqrt(x+1))

(sin(sqrt(x) - sin(sqrt(x+1)) = -2lim -> infinity cos (sqrt(x) + sqrt(x+1))/2 sin (1/2(sqrt(x+1)+sqrt(x))

sin goes against 0 because the denominator goes against 0